# ruby - syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting ')' for if (id == 53 or id == 54)

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
 if id == 53 or id == 54
```

I tried

```
if id == 53 || 54
```

but the results are invalid as that is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
if [53,54].include? id
  #do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an operator precedence issue.  The == operator has a higher priority than ||.

from irb:

```
1 == 2 or 1 == 3
=> false

1 == 2 or 3
=> 2 (which evaluates in an expression as true)
```

If we play with your original code:

```
id = 7
id == 53 or id == 54
=> false
id == 53 || 54
=> 55 (which would evaluate to true)
```